# Quarkus - Deploy in Raspberry PI

Tags: quarkus

i would like to deploy my Quarkus app in a raspberry pi with jvm mode. But this image registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.4 is not compatible with arm.

```
Linux ubuntu 5.11.0-1012-raspi #13-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 17 10:47:05 UTC 2021 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I don't know if this feature is / will be planned but in doubt, i ask this problem. I will try with native image.

Edit : i've just seen this issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-images/issues/83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ubi8 images for arm but only for 64 bits OS's. It's working for me on Ubuntu server 64 bits:

```
Linux ubuntu 5.11.0-1007-raspi #7-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 14 22:08:05 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.
I verify with "arch" command and the result is "armv7l", so as i see on diferents posts, represents 32 bits. I'm going to switch OS to be in 64 bits 